# Android emulator never finishes booting when "-no-window" flag is used

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, android-emulator, qemu, android-virtual-device

My goal is to run the Android emulator in "-no-window" mode because I want to run it on a remote machine which does not have a monitor / graphics card attached. I have been struggling for days without success.

First, let me describe what works. I will then describe what doesn't, which is really what I want to achieve.

**What is working**

I can run the emulator on the remote machine without the "-no-window" flag. The remote machine is a bare metal machine (it's not a virtual machine) with Ubuntu installed. When the emulator runs, I can "see" it on my local display. Here is what I did:

1. I ssh into the remote machine with the "-Y" flag so that the rendering will appear on my local machine:

> ```
> ssh -Y username@my-remote-machine
> ```

2. When connected to the remote machine over ssh, I would execute the emulator using this command:

> ```
> $ uname -a 
> Linux cell1 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator
>
> ./emulator  -show-kernel -no-boot-anim -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Nexus_5X_API_22_64bit
> ```

3. I then waited a bit and the emulator would appear on my client machine under a minute.
4. I explored the UI a little bit and then pressed Ctrl-C in the console to stop the emulator gracefully. Things worked as expected and I saw the following in the console:

> ```
> [  123.257075] healthd: battery l=100 v=0 t=0.0 h=2 st=2 chg=a
> ^C
> emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 132314 ms
> ```

**What is not working**

1. I connected to the remote machine in the same way.
2. Then, I attempted to run the emulator with the "-no-window" flag because - ultimately - I want to run the emulator from within a cronjob and there will be no DISPLAY for it to appear in.

> ```
> ./emulator  -show-kernel -no-boot-anim -netdelay none -netspeed full
> -no-snapshot-load -avd Nexus_5X_API_22_64bit  -no-window
> ```

3. I waited 3 minutes in the hope that it would finish booting. But my hope was let down. How did I know the booting didn't finish? I learned that when I pressed Ctrl-C and saw the following in the console:

> ```
> shell@generic_x86_64:/ $
> ^C
> emulator: WARNING: Skipping state saving as emulator not finished booting.
> ```

My question is: does anyone know why the emulator didn't finish booting with the "-no-window" flag? How can I run the emulator on a remote machine (a bare metal machine) without a monitor? Any suggestion / help is appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve? I'm stuck with this problem too

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into the same problem. I successfully managed to boot once with `-no-window`, but all subsequent attempts failed after using the emulator with a window for a bit.

From what I have found, it **seems** it may be something to do with the state being persisted (even though launching with `-no-window` makes it detect a configuration change, and thus should be resetting the state).

If I launch with `emulator -no-window -wipe-data -avd TEST_1234` (i.e. wiping the previous state), it will finish the boot process successfully, every time.

Subsequent launches using `-no-window` without `-wipe-data` also seem to work too:

```
$ emulator -no-window -avd TEST_1234           
^Cemulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 30735 ms
```

It's not an ideal solution if you need to switch between using the UI and using a headless configuration, but if you (like me) were just switching to the UI to visually verify something, and intend to manage everything using `adb` in production, this should get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for some time. Try adding these params to the emulator startup:

`-qemu -enable-kvm -snapshot`

Answer (score 0):

It costed me a full day to understand that it was a simply image issue. Switching from the google apis versions to default ones fixed my problem.

Hope it helps